# The type 'XX' is not assignable to service

Tags: autofac

Now I get a problem on registering generic components, here is my error message:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
namespace ProjectFrameworkRepository.InventoryRepository
{
    public class InventoryAgentRepository :EntityRepository<InventoryAgent,ProjectDataContext>, IInventoryAgentRepository
    {
        public InventoryAgentRepository(IServiceLocator serviceLocator) : base(serviceLocator)
        {
        }
    }
}

#region 注册服务Repository
builder.RegisterType<InventoryAgentRepository>().As<IInventoryAgentRepository>().SingleInstance();

#region 注册服务接口
builder.RegisterType<InventoryAgentService>().As<IInventoryAgentService>().SingleInstance();
```

Comment: Could you include the exact error message ?

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I have similar issue